# Use WooCommerce function in other Wordpress plugin

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am currently trying to make a plugin which updates the stock count of my WooCommerce products. 
So I wanted to access the wc_update_product_stock function, but an error got returned instead.

Code in plugin php file:

> wc_update_product_stock($id,$stock);

error in log:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function wc_update_product_stock()

I read somewhere, that a normal call of all WC functions should be possible, if the WooCommerce Plugin is activated.

**Update:**

I tried your code inside a function as Scriptonomy suggested

> ```
>     function updateWCProduct($product)
>     {         
>         $wcproduct = new WC_Product($product->get_id());
>         var_dump($wcproduct);
>         $wcproduct->set_stock($product->get_stock(),'set');
>         $wcproduct->set_price($product->get_price());
>     }
> ```

but I get a empty product object back

> object(WC_Product)#9573 (5) {   ["id"]=>   int(9834)   ["post"]=>
>   NULL   ["product_type"]=>   NULL   ["shipping_class":protected]=>
>   string(0) ""   ["shipping_class_id":protected]=>   int(0) }

**Update:**
To get the product by sku use the code here:
https://www.skyverge.com/blog/find-product-sku-woocommerce/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've already invoked the product, e.g. with

`$product = new WC_Product($id);`

then you can update the stock level with

`$product->set_stock($stock);`

For more information check the documentation:

https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_set_stock

Comment: This answer doesn't work for me. I have the product (I'm logging it out and I can see all its attributes), $stock is a valid integer, and I get no errors in the log when I do `$product->set_stock($stock);` but the change is just not written to the DB. What could be going wrong?

Comment: Arggghh. Never mind the comment above. I was trying to set_stock() on a product that did not have managing_stock set to `yes`. Toggled that and now this works perfectly.

Comment: `set_stock` works for me but `set_price` doesn't, not sure whats wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The Woocommerce plugin must be loaded and initiated before you can call any functions of the sort.

Hook onto the `woocommerce_init` action and execute your code there.

`add_action( 'woocommerce_init', 'callback');`

Comment: Valid point from your side!